# numbers of cv pages

Tags: cv

I want to number the pages of this CV https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/murats-cv-template/gfwjwshrzqgd, but I can't, despite I use the \setcounter{1}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a document [class without page numbering](https://github.com/muratcankaracabey/latex_cv/blob/970e310a110004a47bda4c0ebd179384e94f3011/muratcan_cv.cls#L23) You need first to [change the pagestyle to plain](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Headers_and_footers#LaTeX_page_styles) (but you'll need some other tweaking I think.) I think this kind of template are not for cv that are more than 2 or 3 pages.

Comment: Thank you, I just  changed the style page to plain and it becomes numbered